# If $x(t)=\cos(2t)$ and $y(t)=\sin(2t)$, find $\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt:

> A curve in the $xy$-plane is defined by the parametric equations $x(t)=\cos(2t)$ and $y(t)=\sin(2t)$ for $t\ge0$. Find $\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}$.

I believe I was able to find an answer for this, I'm just looking for some clarification as to whether or not this answer might actually be correct or not.

I was able to come up with an answer of $2$, after I found that square-root equation to be equal to the following: $\sqrt{(2\cos(2x))^2+(-2\sin(2x))^2}$, and I evaluated from there.

Any help/clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you find is correct.

Using
$$
x'(t)=-2\sin(2t)\quad y'(t)=2\cos(2t)
$$
and $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, you conclude that
$$
\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}=2
$$